# Estimating minimum output voltage of common-source from ID-VDS graphs

Tags: circuit-analysis

In this example problem ([see the full problem here](https://i.imgur.com/PAl8YsE.png), I copied relevant parts into the question below), there are set of \$I_D-V_{DS}\$ characteristics from the NMOS and PMOS devices of a common-source amplifier corresponding to the amplifier below. The problem is to estimate the minimum allowable output voltage for the amplifier to the highest precision possible. The given answer to the problem is that the minimum allowable output voltage is \$1.2\ V\$. I'm not sure how to get this level of precision from the given info.

There are two curves for the NMOS device as its characteristic is plotted for both \$V_G=2 \ V\$ and \$V_G=2.1 \ V\$.

[image: amp]
[image: graphs]

My process: The minimum output allowable voltage of the amplifier should be the lowest voltage allowing the NMOS to stay in saturation, so \$V_{o,min}=V_{OV,N}=V_{GS,N}-V_{TH,N}\$. From the NMOS's curve on the graph for \$2 \ V\$ at the gate, this looks to occur at around 1 V. To be quantitative, since the additional curve for \$V_G=2.1\ V\$ is provided, \$g_m\$ can be estimated as \$g_m\approx\frac{\Delta I}{\Delta VGS}\approx\frac{0.5\ mA}{0.1\ V}=5\ mS\$. From the intersection point on the curve (which is the amplifier operating point), \$I_D\approx2.5 \ mA\$. Then, from \$V_{OV}=\frac{2I_D}{g_m}\$, we have \$V_{OV}=1\ V\$, just like the graph suggests.

There's no other information given. Is there some other implied information/assumption that leads to the answer of \$1.2\ V\$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, gain of the amplifier is approximately (5-2.8)/(2.1-2) = 22
Minimum allowed output voltage is theoretically when **VDSn = VGSn-VTHn**
Let us assume that this happens at a VGSn = 2.1 + x
In that case, VDSn = 2.8 - 22x and the overall equation is
2.8 - 22x = 2.1 + x - 1  (where VTHn = 1V)
Solving for x gives 0.07 and hence, minimum output voltage is 1.17V

Comment: Thanks a lot! Forgot about taking into account the VOV increase as VOUT decreases.